# How to use multiple GridView ItemTemplate's (WinRT/XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have created a GridView interface with tiles of varying sizes (like the Windows start screen). How can I position controls differently on each tile? My code currently looks like this:

```
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="500" Width="1000">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding TileColor}"/>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding TextColor}" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,10,720,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding TextColor}" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Height="334" Margin="10,0,336,15" RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.59"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

but because of the varying tile heights it doesn't layout correctly. Is there a way I can define multiple ItemTemplates?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create multiple data templates and then u need to use DataTemplateSelector to map them to your tiles. I think this article will answer your question perfectly!

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/08/06/multiple-item-templates-in-windows-phone.aspx